# ES2015 module syntax is preferred over custom TypeScript modules and namespaces @typescript-eslint/no-namespace #2

Tags: typescript, eslint, typing, typescript-eslint

Many years I had been used following code

```js
export interface User {
  readonly name: User.Name;
  readonly address: User.Address;
}

export namespace User {
  export interface Name {
    readonly first: string;
    readonly last: string;
  }

  export interface Address {
    readonly country: string;
    readonly city: string;
  }
}
```

I like `Name` and `Address` interfaces accessible via `User` interface, that helps to prevent name conflicts, show relation, etc.

Right now, I have a fight with ESLint rule [@typescript-eslint/no-namespace](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-namespace/)

Is it possible to achieve same typing without violation of the rule?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use a *namespace* without violating the lint rule.

However you could do-away with the namespace entirely by inlining your types:

```
export interface User {
  readonly name: {
    readonly first: string;
    readonly last: string;
  };
  readonly address: {
    readonly country: string;
    readonly city: string;
  };
}
```

If you want to specifically reference the address or name type later in code you can then do so using an indexed type reference:

```
type UserName = User['name'];
type UserAddress = User['address'];
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgVQGc04BvAKDjimEwBMIkAbATziUwFtgAuMyqtVoNmbdAiiEYfKVGQBzANwCqNeo1ZwmmKTJhykSgQF9lq4Rrb06NQoT4VBQ9aLjYIAVxRQWeg0ac1EU1sBBhfOFkFMzhTcmNycnCwPCI0ADkuPABeAmIoAG0Acg5uIoBdZQB6KqcAPQB+JJYUvLQAQTobYDs4XLTCoutbQgrq2sFGoA)